# My iPhone 6 was stolen along with my router from my home

Tags: passwords, wifi, iphone

The router was a secondary one that was no longer being used. The person who did this is my ex-friend/roommate so the wifi password was also known. With me being confused as to what was going on at first (on my new iPhone) I didn’t change the password or make sure my last SIM card was deactivated.

She accessed all of my texts, mail, my apps, which lead to my security cameras and even my garage door. So to my understanding, she could see everything on my new iPhone and my laptop.

Now my laptop is stuck on the sign-on screen. I’ve since been trying to do some damage control; I reported her, I removed that iPhone from my account, deactivated the SIM card, changed our wireless password. But now this:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? It was accompanied by some weird radio wave sound.

The other main question I have is: can she be traced to be responsible for this? Because I would love to see justice.

Comment: Look at the address in your address bar of the iPhone screenshot. Doesn't look like Apple.com to me...  If you signed in to that page then it's game over, they've got your Apple ID password.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with SomeGuy - Consider this a total compromise. Start changing ALL of your passwords for all of your accounts. Use strong passwords and setup Two-Factor Authentication to ensure you're protected. 
I had someone swipe my debit card and was able to get all my information, including SS# and access my bank account. They spoofed my phone number, called to get things reset on my account, and were able to answer my security questions by researching basic information about me.
This prompted me to change everything, and change the way I answer security questions. I now set all my security questions to purposely wrong answers, but only answers I would know. Something like: who was your bride's maid at your wedding? - and set it to your dog. Something that you would know but not something that could be researched or Googled by a stranger. 
Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This screen is clearly not Apple and looks as if it's trying to render non-English-ASCII or the like in an English language which has not been downloaded to your phone.

The best example to explain it would be like a computer trying to display Russian symbols using English alphabet but Russian hasn't been downloaded, or trying to 'cat' a binary file in Linux - it would show up gibberish. Now add a mobile web platform with even less capabilities and you have this.

### Damage control

Change your apple password right now, as well as any other passwords you've used on your phone (Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.) Remove any debit/credit cards or bank account info connected to your Apple account. For safe measures, you'll want to replace ALL of your debt/credit cards (don't be lazy in assuming they didn't get that one card you don't use often... it sounds like you were fully compromised).

I would also run a full antivirus and malware scan on anything on your home network. [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) is a good, free use for Windows, but others are good as well. Treat and use all computers/tablets/phones on your network as if they are infected with **ALL** of your personal info until you **know** otherwise.

Finally, your question

> the other main question I have is can she be traced to be responsible
>   for this? Because I would love to see justice.

- This question has 2 parts. It appears to me that your hacked Apple is not necessarily due to her actions, so that would probably not be prosecuted. The
  challenge you will run in to is that IT crimes are notoriously
  difficult to trace and prove in a court of law. It's not out of the
  question, but only about 1% of cyber crimes are prosecuted for
  reasons outside the scope of this question. The conviction rate for larceny or
  theft is much more likely, which leads me to point 2.
- As for her stealing stuff, yes, absolutely she can be held
  responsible. The laws exist and are certainly enforceable. This would be much easier to prove than cybercrimes.

Good luck.